# Closing a two year old question as a duplicate of a one year old question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I just noticed that [Is there a measure of code rot?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/50819/is-there-a-measure-of-code-rot/50821#50821), which was created in February 2011 was closed two weeks ago as a duplicate of [How can I quantify the amount of technical debt that exists in a project?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/135993/how-can-i-quantify-the-amount-of-technical-debt-that-exists-in-a-project), which is a year younger.

Putting aside for a moment my annoyance at people seemingly randomly closing old inactive questions like that, what earthly purpose does it serve to close an older question as a duplicate of a newer one?  If anything, it should be the other way around.

[Turn away a bug if no reproducible test case exists?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/61558/turn-away-a-bug-if-no-reproducible-test-case-exists), https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/45230/do-programmers-at-non-software-companies-need-the-same-things-as-at-software-com, [How do you know you're writing good code?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/61655/how-do-you-know-youre-writing-good-code), and [Code Smell: Inheritance Abuse](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12439/code-smell-inheritance-abuse?lq=1) are other examples.

Comment: related MSO discussion: [Why is an older question marked as duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182868/165773) (with several duplicate discussions, helping to understand this issue in more details)

Comment: I notices this earlier and decided to consistently skip such reviews if I encounter them in the queues. I don't want to spend the effort to decide if the duplicate vote is justified or not for such old questions.

Answer (score 6):

While in general the newer question should be closed as a duplicate of the older, there are occasions when the new question is "better" (in some way):

- It expresses the problem more succinctly.
- There's a better answer

etc.

In these cases it's perfectly acceptable for the older question to be closed as a duplicate of the newer.

Comment: I understand that exception, but do you think that condition applies to any of the questions I linked?  They seem roughly equivalent to me.

Answer (score 3):

(wrote this as an answer, it got a little too long for a comment)

For the examples given, compare the following stats:

### 1

- [Is there a measure of code rot?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/50819/is-there-a-measure-of-code-rot)

  - Asked 2 years ago
  - Viewed 860 times
  - Rep 17 / 5 favorites
  - 5 answers (accepted answer rep 7)
  - Active 15 days ago (duped August 26)
- [How can I quantify the amount of technical debt that exists in a project?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/135993/how-can-i-quantify-the-amount-of-technical-debt-that-exists-in-a-project)

  - Asked 1 year ago
  - Viewed 1868 times
  - Rep 31 / 14 favorites
  - 10 answers (accepted answer rep 24)

---

### 2

- [Turn away a bug if no reproducible test case exists?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/61558/turn-away-a-bug-if-no-reproducible-test-case-exists)

  - Asked 2 years ago
  - 1073 views
  - Rep 10 / 2 favorites
  - 11 answers / Accepted answer 17 rep
  - Active 3 months ago (closed June 14th)
- [How do I isolate difficult to reproduce bugs?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/102819/how-do-i-isolate-difficult-to-reproduce-bugs)

  - Asked 2 years ago
  - 494 views
  - Rep 12 / 6 favorites
  - 4 answers / Accepted answer 24 rep

This looks to be the right relationship.  While the views is lower, the rep is higher.  The answer appears to be more authoritative and less opinionated.

---

### 3

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/45230/do-programmers-at-non-software-companies-need-the-same-things-as-at-software-com

  - Asked 2 years ago
  - 352 views
  - Rep 5 / no favs
  - 4 answers, no accepted answer, top answer 11 rep
  - Active 2 years ago (Closed April 13th)
- [What's the difference between working at a software company and a company whose focus is in another field?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/96729/whats-the-difference-between-working-at-a-software-company-and-a-company-whose)

  - Asked 2 years ago
  - 2210 views
  - Rep 22 / 6 favs
  - 10 answers, accepted answer 32 rep

---

### 4

- [How do you know you're writing good code?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/61655/how-do-you-know-youre-writing-good-code)

  - Asked 2 years ago
  - 13k views
  - Rep 191 / 95 favs
  - 31 answers, accepted answer 240 rep
  - Active 1 year ago (closed March 27th)
- [How would you know if you've written readable and easily maintainable code?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141005/how-would-you-know-if-youve-written-readable-and-easily-maintainable-code)

  - Asked 1 year ago
  - 5964 views
  - 76 rep / 26 favs
  - 21 answers, accepted answer 116 rep

This one you might be able to argue a reversal on... though I do have a slight preference for the answers in the 'master' over the 'dup'.

---

### 5

- [Code Smell: Inheritance Abuse](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12439/code-smell-inheritance-abuse)

  - Asked 2 years ago
  - 2673 views
  - Rep 34 / 10 favorites
  - 10 answers, no accepted, top answer rep 31
  - Active 8 months ago (Closed June 29th)
- [Where does this concept of "favor composition over inheritance" come from?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/65179/where-does-this-concept-of-favor-composition-over-inheritance-come-from)

  - Asked 2 years ago
  - 12k views
  - Rep 57 / 33 favorites
  - 16 answers, accepted answer rep 65

---

Judging by these metrics, the dup relationship seems to be reasonable as those are the ones that people have voted up and find when looking for that problem more often.

Are there any specific ones were there is some reason why the relationship should be reversed from what they currently are?

I would also contend the "people seemingly randomly closing old inactive questions" -- they are not all inactive (some activated just before their closure).  Furthermore, inactive questions (especialy popular ones) often attract attention of new, well meaning new users who want to add their $0.02 in this forum.  Yes, I know its not a forum.