# Update required for the close questions help page?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, duplicate-questions, help-center, privileges

Referring to: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions

Specifically for duplicates it states:

> **When should I vote to close a question?**
>
> Questions should be closed by
>   casting close votes if:
>
> - they are sufficiently similar to existing questions and *would be answered identically to them*.
> - they are unclear, too broad, or otherwise problematic to identifying the problem in a way that can be
> - properly addressed by answerers they are sufficiently off-topic, as outlined in the help center.

(emphasis mine)

I was in a discussion this morning on this question: [Should I throw guard exceptions that will be thrown by internal methods anyway?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/255148/should-i-throw-guard-exceptions-that-will-be-thrown-by-internal-methods-anyway?noredirect=1#comment552707_255148)

Whereby it was marked as a duplicate to a question that was several months newer, I expressed confusion and was directed to this meta post:

[Closing a two year old question as a duplicate of a one year old question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6160/closing-a-two-year-old-question-as-a-duplicate-of-a-one-year-old-question)

Regardless of whether or not it was a correct move, I believe the information on the help page does not cover this policy and should be updated.

The current use of *would be* in the help text implies that a question, as it currently stands, has not yet been answered, or is likely to receive newer answers and implies that perhaps this close reason is best suited to new questions. I don't believe that is the case in my situation, and so the help text should be updated to cover closing as duplicate older questions in line with the meta post I linked above to avoid confusion.

Do you agree?